# Application Unity UI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

Two days ago I started creating an application for a friend using a tutorial on youtube. Basically I'm trying to create an app with a timer. Simple background, simple script. This is the code I'm using:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text TimerText;
    public float countdownTime = 181;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        countdownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        int minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(countdownTime / 60F);
        int seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(countdownTime - minutes * 60);
        string niceTime = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
        TimerText.text = niceTime;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can't figure it out how to make a button that when its first pressed it should start the timer and when its pressed second it should reset it. I've just started using c#.

https://prnt.sc/rcknb8 (this is what I got till now)

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable "countdownTime" back to its default number when the button is pressed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
    public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text TimerText;
    public float countdownTime = 0;
    public float defaultCountdownTime = 181;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(countdownTime > 0)
        {           
            countdownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            int minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(countdownTime / 60F);
            int seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(countdownTime - minutes * 60);
            string niceTime = string.Format("{0:0}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
            TimerText.text = niceTime;
        }

    }

    void ButtonPress()
    {
        countdownTime = defaultCountdownTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the timer does not even start. The "COUNTDOWN" text does not change.

Comment: @SenZoR666 well did you make your button invoke the method `ButtonPress`?

Comment: You have to make the Buttonpress call the "ButtonPress()" method.

Comment: I've tried but it wont show the function. (https://prnt.sc/rcl86n)

Comment: it needs to be `public`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the parameters initialized before and then make a simple calculation using modulo

"""For instances guys, i create a simple SkaterBoard game using simple gravity physics with Android Studio, I would really appreciate if you could left a review on it."""

(Android Link) Skater Soldier Game: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fight.exempleclass